# Executing XPROC

Tags: xml, xslt, pipeline, xproc

Am very new to XSLT and XPROC stuffs. Now i have written my sample XPROC, As like every beginner, i also started with **Hello World**.

**hello.xpl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:pipeline xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step" xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc" name="pipeline">
<p:identity>
<p:input port="source">
<p:inline>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</p:inline>
</p:input>
</p:identity>
</p:pipeline>
```

Now my question may be silly, I want to know how to execute this and view the output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Download Calabash](http://xmlcalabash.com/) (a FLOSS XProc processor) and run it on your pipeline.

Comment: You will need Java to run XMLCalabash, but if it is in your path, and you have the calabash.jar in the same directory as your hello.xpl, you run it with this command-line: java -jar calabash.jar hello.xpl

Comment: @grtjn: I do not know of any freely available implementation of XProc that does not require Java (see http://xproc.org/implementations/).

Comment: that remark was meant for i2ijeya. But apart from xprocxq (written in XQuery) you are right.

Comment: Is there a IDE with compilation error prompt and debug by step through? Thanks